# Run arquillian tests on jboss installed on remote cloud server

Tags: cloud, jboss-arquillian

I am able to run arquillian tests on my local machine using eclipse/terminal. I tried running arquillian from my local machine to jboss deployed on cloud server. I am sure that the dependencies are properly added.
This is how I login to cloud server:

`ssh -p xxxx root@cloud.abcd.pqr.wxy.xyz`

Part of my `arquillian.xml`:

```
<container qualifier="jboss_remote" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="managementAddress">cloud.abcd.pqr.wxy.xyz</property>
        <property name="managementPort ">9999</property>
        <property name="username">root</property>
        <property name="password">shroot</property>
        <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>
        <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">true</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

Please see the console output when I run arquillian tests

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not start container
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:167)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.start(CommonDeployableContainer.java:113)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Managed server was not started within [60] s
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:163)
    ... 77 more
```

---

Another thing I noticed is that in arquillian.xml when I give managementAddress and managementPort as 127.0.0.1:9999, it works .
but when I try putting managementAddress and managementPort as myIP:9999, it doesnt work.

The issue why I was not able to deploy using arquillian to remote Jboss with managementAddress and managementPort as myIP:9999 was I did not configured my standalone.xml properly, this is what I have modified in standalone.xml

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Now when I am trying to run arquillian tests on remote jboss, arquillian deploys the shrinkwrap ear but unable to run test cases. This is the exception I am getting:
`Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 5, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.118 sec <<< FAILURE!
basicSanitytest(test.integration.pm.parser.ejb.PMFileParserTest)  Time elapsed: 0.019 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching test test.integration.pm.parser.ejb.PMFileParserTest public void test.integration.pm.parser.ejb.PMFileParserTest.basicSanitytest()
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:120)
..........
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching request at http://0.0.0.0:8080/test/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=test.integration.pm.parser.ejb.PMFileParserTest&methodName=basicSanitytest. No result returned
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.executeWithRetry(ServletMethodExecutor.java:162)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:122)
    ... 90 more`

Comment: remote jboss is in started state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, it did not worked so what we did is installed jboss on the server jenkins was installed and now local-arquillian is working.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use the managed container connector for Arquillian, when you should be using the remote.

The username/password should be the JBoss Management console username/password (typically admin/admin)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an issue with arquillian, already reported and fixed with the following version :

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>`